# SQLAlchemy order_by ASC using nulls_last raises ProgrammingError (Google Spanner DB)

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, google-cloud-spanner

I'm trying to be able to dynamically sort a query by a given column name and have nulls be placed at the end of the list.  It works fine when using `desc` ordering, but raises a `ProgrammingError` when trying to use `nulls_last` with `asc` order.  It appears this error is being raised as the result of an `InvalidArgument` error (see Traces below).

#### Dependencies

- sqlalchemy = "~1.4.37"
- sqlalchemy-spanner = "~1.2.0"

We're using Google Cloud Spanner for our database.

#### Original Query

##### Generating Method

```py
@classmethod
def get_my_models(cls, sort_by: str, order_by: str) -> List["MyModel"]:
  with read_session_scope(get_engine()) as session:
    sort_attr = getattr(MyModel, sort_by)

      query = (
        session.query(MyModel)
        .filter(func.coalesce(MyModel.is_deleted, False).is_(False))
        .order_by(nulls_last(getattr(sort_attr, order_by)()))
      )
  return [MyModel.from_orm(model) for model in query.all()]
```

##### Translated Query

When called with `sort_by="my_column"` and `order_by="desc"`

```sql
SELECT ... FROM my_model WHERE coalesce(my_model.is_deleted, false) IS false ORDER BY 
my_model.my_column DESC NULLS LAST
```

The above works fine.  So as long as I want to order by descending, I'm good. Unfortunately, that's not the requirement.

When called with `sort_by="my_column"` and `order_by="asc"`

```sql
SELECT ... FROM my_model WHERE coalesce(my_model.is_deleted, false) IS false ORDER BY 
my_model.my_column ASC NULLS LAST
```

it looks great, but it raises:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (google.cloud.spanner_dbapi.exceptions.ProgrammingError)
```

The error is raised in the last line of the query method during `query.all()`

#### Traces

```
File "/opt/pysetup/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2768, in all
    return self._iter().all()
  File "/opt/pysetup/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2903, in _iter
    result = self.session.execute(
  File "/opt/pysetup/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1712, in execute
    result = conn._execute_20(statement, params or {}, execution_options)
  File "/opt/pysetup/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1631, in _execute_20
    return meth(self, args_10style, kwargs_10style, execution_options)
  File "/opt/pysetup/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 332, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_clauseelement(
  File "/opt/pysetup/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1498, in _execute_clauseelement
    ret = self._execute_context(
  File "/opt/pysetup/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1862, in _execute_context
    self._handle_dbapi_exception(
  File "/opt/pysetup/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2043, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    util.raise_(
  File "/opt/pysetup/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 208, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "/opt/pysetup/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1819, in _execute_context
    self.dialect.do_execute(
  File "/opt/pysetup/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/cloud/sqlalchemy_spanner/sqlalchemy_spanner.py", line 1006, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
  File "/opt/pysetup/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/cloud/spanner_dbapi/cursor.py", line 70, in wrapper
    return function(cursor, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/pysetup/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/cloud/spanner_dbapi/cursor.py", line 286, in execute
    raise ProgrammingError(getattr(e, "details", e))
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (google.cloud.spanner_dbapi.exceptions.ProgrammingError) []
```

```
self = <google.cloud.spanner_dbapi.cursor.Cursor object at 0xffffacfca220>
sql = 'SELECT ... coalesce(my_model.is_deleted, @a0) IS false ORDER BY my_model.my_column ASC NULLS LAST'
args = {'a0': False}

    @check_not_closed
    def execute(self, sql, args=None):
        """Prepares and executes a Spanner database operation.
    
        :type sql: str
        :param sql: A SQL query statement.
    
        :type args: list
        :param args: Additional parameters to supplement the SQL query.
        """
        self._result_set = None
    
        try:
            if self.connection.read_only:
                self._handle_DQL(sql, args or None)
                return
    
            class_ = parse_utils.classify_stmt(sql)
            if class_ == parse_utils.STMT_DDL:
                self._batch_DDLs(sql)
                if self.connection.autocommit:
                    self.connection.run_prior_DDL_statements()
                return
    
            # For every other operation, we've got to ensure that
            # any prior DDL statements were run.
            # self._run_prior_DDL_statements()
            self.connection.run_prior_DDL_statements()
    
            if class_ == parse_utils.STMT_UPDATING:
                sql = parse_utils.ensure_where_clause(sql)
    
            if class_ != parse_utils.STMT_INSERT:
                sql, args = sql_pyformat_args_to_spanner(sql, args or None)
    
            if not self.connection.autocommit:
                statement = Statement(
                    sql,
                    args,
                    get_param_types(args or None)
                    if class_ != parse_utils.STMT_INSERT
                    else {},
                    ResultsChecksum(),
                    class_ == parse_utils.STMT_INSERT,
                )
    
                (
                    self._result_set,
                    self._checksum,
                ) = self.connection.run_statement(statement)
                while True:
                    try:
                        self._itr = PeekIterator(self._result_set)
                        break
                    except Aborted:
                        self.connection.retry_transaction()
                return
    
            if class_ == parse_utils.STMT_NON_UPDATING:
                self._handle_DQL(sql, args or None)
            elif class_ == parse_utils.STMT_INSERT:
                _helpers.handle_insert(self.connection, sql, args or None)
            else:
                self.connection.database.run_in_transaction(
                    self._do_execute_update, sql, args or None
                )
        except (AlreadyExists, FailedPrecondition, OutOfRange) as e:
            raise IntegrityError(getattr(e, "details", e))
        except InvalidArgument as e:
>           raise ProgrammingError(getattr(e, "details", e))
E           sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (google.cloud.spanner_dbapi.exceptions.ProgrammingError) []
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Cloud Spanner databases using the standard GoogleSQL dialect always sort `NULL` first when the sort order is ascending, and `NULL` last when the sort order is descending. The SQL dialect allows you to specify `ASC NULLS FIRST` and `DESC NULLS LAST`, as those correspond with the default, but not to actually change the sort order.

A workaround for this would be to use a `COALESCE(my_column, <large-value>)` expression in your `ORDER BY` clause. The feasibility of this workaround depends a little on the data type of the column that you are sorting. If it is for example an `INT64` column, you could just use the max value for `INT64`. Be aware though that such a workaround can make your query less efficient, as the `ORDER BY` clause will not be able to use any index that you might have defined on the column.

Comment: I was just looking into the features of GoogleSQL and playing with queries in DBeaver and found this to be true.  Thanks for the quick reply.  How unfortunate